# Call API method undefinitely (Check status)

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework

Is there a method to call a function in Angular (or Ionic) infinitely without stopping?

I'm simulating a payment process. Here's the process : I send a payment using a POST Method, the API sends me to a URL that gives me the status of the payment.

On my side, I have to wait until I get this payment status from the back. So I have a method that checks the status.
I would like to call this method infinitely until I get the status.

I saw that there was "ng-repeat" in Angular but I'm not working on the HTML template, it's in my TypeScript file.

Here is my code :

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.paymentService.postPayment(id, total, currency).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        
// Here I want to check status undefinitely
    this.paymentService.checkStatus().subscribe({
      next: (result) => {
  // WHEN RESULT IS SUCCESS,  DO REDIRECTION...
      this.router.navigate(['...']);
      },
      error: () => {
            
      },
    });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide your code sample. Without it, everyone is left to guesswork.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that wouldn't bring any help

Comment: Hi @Eikichi, I would say you're challenge here is less related with Angular itself but more with designing a mechanism for relaunching an http call until it satisfies your goal. Also, your code is in Angular, but the question is tagged for AngularJS (which is a different thing). Please improve the title, tags and provide more details as for what you're trying to achieve. Cheers 

Comment: Sorry I don't have a lot of experience, I'm still learning, thanks for your advice, I've edited and I hope it's good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to learn more about RxJs and HTTP requests.

The main idea is to create an http request observable using Angular's `HttpClient`, then `.pipe()` it with RxJs operators to make it retry on failure.

Here's an example from Angular's docs:

```js
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
    .pipe(
      retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
      catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
    );
}
```

I'm guessing you would have to modify it and apply some operators to tell RxJs how you define failure/success for your request, but without more details it's not easy to say.

[Retrying a failed request](https://angular.io/guide/http#retrying-a-failed-request) | [RxJs operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what i was looking for